# Validation Error: Preset @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest not found

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-cli

While executing Jest Test in PHPStorm I receive the following error in the console.

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58148/15341a94-78d6-4475-94d6-c89c7e9e3c39
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
● Validation Error:

  Preset @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest not found.

  Configuration Documentation:
  https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html

Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

I tried to `$ vue add @vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest` in order to add plugin but error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Jest Run/Debug Configuration 'Jest Package' path had to be changed to `/your-project-path/node_modules/@vue/cli-service`